# [PHP][Laravel] Cant show/get column from another table using Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

im trying to show or get column from another table using eloquent laravel, but it seems i have miss something or typo. Im using Laravel 9, and i've followed all the instructions video and documentation and all of them seems to be not working.

Error message says : Attempt to read property "deskripsi" on null

Migrations :

- table bisnis :

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('t_bisnis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('deskripsi', 255);
            $table->string('pemilik', 255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('t_bisnis');
    }
```

- table group :

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('t_grup_layanan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('bisnis_id')->nullable()->index('fk_bisnis_to_grup');
            $table->string('deskripsi', 255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('t_grup_layanan');
    }
```

Models :

- bisnis :

```html
class Business extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 't_bisnis';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primary_key = 'id';
    protected $with = ['group'];
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'deskripsi',
        'pemilik'
    ];

    public function group(){
        return $this->hasOne(GroupService::class);
    }

}
```

- group :

```html
class GroupService extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 't_grup_layanan';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primary_key = '';
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'bisnis_id',
        'deskripsi'
    ];
    protected $with = [];

    public function service(){
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }    

    public function business()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Business::class);
    }
    
}
```

My blade :

```html
@foreach ($list as $item)    
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item->business->deskripsi }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item->deskripsi }}</td>
              <td>{{ $item->updated_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
              <td>
                {{-- <a href="#" class="badge bg-success"><span data-feather="eye"></span></a> --}}
                <a href="{{ route('gruplayanan.edit', $item->id) }}" class="badge bg-warning"><span data-feather="edit"></span></a>
                <form action="{{ route('gruplayanan.delete', $item->id) }}" method="post" class="d-inline">
                @method('delete')
                @csrf
                <button class="badge bg-danger border-0" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><span data-feather="x-circle"></span></button>
                </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

My controller :

```html
class GroupServiceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $list = GroupService::all();
        return view('dashboard.gruplayanan.main', compact('list'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a **belongsTo** relation in a model it automatically assumes that the relation key is **{the name of the function}_id**.

In your case it looks for a **business_id** field in the **t_grup_layanan** table, because your function name is business.

You can override this behavior by giving a second parametor to the belongs to function which is the foreign key name.

```
public function business()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Business::class, 'bisnis_id');
}
```

This should do the trick.

You can find information about this in the official documentation if you scroll down just a little [here](https://You%20can%20find%20it%20in%20the%20documenation%20if%20your%20scroll%20down%20just%20a%20little%20bit%20here%20-%20https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Further to the above you can also do something like `{{ $item->business->deskripsi ?? 'No business associated' }}` if you want to provide a value when this condition is null